# Make video player using mpv player vb.nt

Tags: vb.net

I want to make video player using MPV player on vb.net
Is there any dll to add it?
I tried dll called mpv-1.dll but when add it to visual studio 2015 he can't read it
I want it to play live video if there any way else please tell me.

Comment: Maybe that helps, even when it comes to VLC instead of MPV players.  It is possible to use a video player with the VLC Control without the VLC having to be installed. On the one hand, this in German. On the other hand, there are images and descriptions in that tutorial.    https://www.vb-paradise.de/index.php/Thread/129883-Videoplayer-mit-dem-VlcControl-ohne-das-der-VLC-installiert-sein-muss/

Comment: Are you know way to do this?